# VSCode Open new view into file

Tags: visual-studio-code

We can use the "split editor" option to make two views into one file.

I'm looking for an option to open the same file in separated tabs like I can do in Sublime Text (open new view of file). Is that possible?

Note: I want to do this **without splitting the view**, so there should be two tabs for the same file within *the same* view container.

Comment: the same thing here, im still using sublime partially since sublime allows multiple tabs on the same file

Comment: Related, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/69111951/836330.  Something similar is coming soon.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I couldn't find anything built-in that lets you do this, nor an existing extension in the marketplace. I thought it should be quite trivial to implement a "Duplicate Tab" command yourself in a [custom extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/overview), but it turns out **VSCode only allows the same resource to be opened *once* within the same view column**.

It's still possible to do this on Windows or macOS, but only by abusing this bug:

[Issues with not case/fragment-normalizing file paths (macOS, Windows) #12448](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/12448)

Here's what the code for the extension looks like:

```ts
'use strict';
import * as vscode from 'vscode';

export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
    vscode.commands.registerCommand("duplicateTab", () => {
        var activeEditor = vscode.window.activeTextEditor;
        if (activeEditor == null) {
            return;
        }
        // HACK!
        const sameFileNameButDifferent = activeEditor.document.fileName.toUpperCase();
        vscode.workspace.openTextDocument(sameFileNameButDifferent).then(document => {
            vscode.window.showTextDocument(document, {preview: false});
        });
    });
}
```

In `package.json`:

```json
"contributes": {
    "commands": [
        {
            "title": "Duplicate Tab",
            "command": "duplicateTab"
        }
    ]
},
```

[image]

Comment: the extension is here but it doesn't work any more: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kxkx5150.new-view-into-file