# Create duplicate tab of an already open file

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would like to create a second tab for an already open file so that I can view and edit different portions of the file in different tabs. I'm aware that you can create a split that puts them side by side, but for reasons of screen real estate this is not an ideal solution. Is there any way to accomplish this natively or using an extension in VSCode without [exploiting a bug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49796757/6150284)?